# How to add page numbers anywhere in the document?

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

How can I add the page numbers of a MS WORD document as a field anywhere in the document. For example I create certificates and with each new page the certificate number is displayed as... Page 1 = 5040-SH-001, Page 2 = 5040-SH-002, etc. Check my the image I have included. Thank you! :)[MY DOCUMENT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCupG.jpg)

Comment: This would require you create a template

Comment: Okay I will work from that vantage point while searching around and attempting the result I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you are supposed to do is to use templates and databases. In fact, Access looks like the right choice to make such things, but it sounds like you're looking for a trick using page numbers as an ID for your certificates. However, the following method is only applicable for simple uses, and should cover what you are asking here.

First of all, page number works better with headings; so you could insert all your fixed parts (the table) into a long header, and then fill its variable parts in the page's main body using, let's say text boxes. But this will look awful and, in fact, inconvenient for many pages.

Instead, you'll make the table in the main body, with the `SEQ` field instead of the page number field:

- In the cell where the certificate no. is, type the fixed part "5040-SH-" (with the dash)
- Wile the cursor is there, press `CTRL` + `F9` to insert a pair of the special field brackets `{}`
- Inside it, copy and paste this `SEQ numb \# "000"`
- Press `F9` to update and show the results.

So for new pages, copy the whole table (with the field inside it) and make a new page and paste it there. The number (generated by the field) may look the same from the previous page, so your fields need to get update. The simplest way to do so is to go to the print preview (`CTRL` + `P`) and go back OR select everything in your document and press `F9`.